# Selector CSS que actué cuando una clase exista

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, scss

Dado el siguiente codigo html donde el div classB puede desaparecer dinamicamente

```
<div class="classA">
    <div class="classB"></div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="classC">
    <div class="classD"><div class="classE"></div></div>
</div>
```

Selector CSS que afecte a classE solo cuando exista classB **utilizando solo CSS** o SCSS

He probado esto pero no funciona

```
.classA .classB + .classC .classD .classE {
    
}
```

Comment: No funciona? Pues normal porque cada clase debería llevar su punto delante para empezar. `.classA .classB...`

Comment: Claramente esto es un deber personal y lo propuesto no tiene sentido para obligar a que te corrijan. Investiga además del selector `:not()`

Comment: ya esta editado el error fue solo al copiar el código stackoverflow pero la prueba se hizo con los puntos

Comment: suena a js no css, además, ya estás haciendo dinámicamente el desaparecer el elemento con `classB` yo en ese momento lo que haría es si desaparece `classB` al elemento con `classE` le agrego otra class `classNoHayClassB` y si aparezco el elemento `classB` pues le quito la class `classNoHayClassB`

Comment: otra opción es la misma lógica pero con `attr`, cambiaría el elemento a `<div class="classE" attr-isClassB="true"></div>` y ya el selector sería simplemente `.classE[isClassB=true] {
    
}`

Answer (score 1):

Tu tienes un `+` el cual selecciona el hermano inmediato pero resulta que entre `classA` y `classC` hay hermanos `div` intermedios, por lo que debes usar `~`, quedando:

```
.classA .classB ~ .classC .classD .classE  /* No es correcto */
```

Lo cual no funcionará, los CSS se leen de derecha a izquierda, este selector es lo mismo que decir

- Selecciona el elemento que tiene `.classE`
- Que es hijo `.classD`
- Que a su vez es hijo de `.classC`
- Que es hermano de `.classB` *(Aquí el problema)*
- Que es hijo de `.classA`

Y `.classC` no es hermano `.classB`

El tema de fondo es ***Poder seleccionar al padre según su hijo*** y no al hijo según su padre como es lo habitual.

Este problema lo tuvimos muchos años hasta que apareció la pseudoclase [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Con lo que tu selector queda:

```
.classA:has(.classB) ~ .classC .classD .classE
```

O bien, tambien podemos quitar `classD` ya que sobra

```
.classA:has(.classB) ~ .classC .classE
```

Por último también podríamos ser rigurosos y poner que

```
.classA:has(.classB) ~ .classC > .classD >.classE
```